# How do you rectify a 3D planar polygon?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a 3D planar (all vertices lie in some plane) polygon with vertices: [(x1, y1, z1) ... (x1, y1, z1)].

[image]

I would like to transform this polygon so that I'm viewing it orthographically (as if I'm looking at it straight on).

[image]

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have no information except for vertex coordinates.

Take three non-collinear (perhaps consequent) vertices `C, A, B`. Calculate normalized vector (divide by vector length)

```
b = (B - A) / |B - A|
```

then normal vector (using vector/cross multiplication)

```
N = b.cross.(A-C) and normalize it
un = N / |N|
```

and another unit vector in polygon plane

```
v = b.cross.n
```

Now we want find such matrix of affine transformations, that transforms vertex `A` into point `(0,0,0)`, edge `AB` will be collinear with `OX` axis, normal will be collinear with `OZ` axis, vector `q` will be collinear with `OY` axis. This all means that rotated polygon will lie in `OXY` plane.

Mathematically: points `A, u=A+b, v=A+q, n=A+un` should be transformed in quadruplet `(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)`. In matrix form

```
      [Ax ux vx nx]   [0 1 0 0]
 M *  [Ay uy vy ny] = [0 0 1 0]
      [Az uz vz nz]   [0 0 0 1]
      [1  1  1  1 ]   [1 1 1 1]
```

or

```
  M * S = D
```

Using matrix inverse

```
  M * S * Sinv = D * Sinv
```

and finally

```
  M = D * Sinv
```

So calculate matrix `M` and multiply it with every vertex coordinates. New coordinates should have zero Z-component (or very small due to numerical errors).

You can perform all described operations with `numpy` library with a little code

[Example with specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769459/convert-points-on-a-3d-plane-to-2d-coordinates/49771112#49771112)

Quick-made implementation in plain Python for reference

```
import math
def calcMatrix(ax, bx, cx, ay, by, cy, az, bz, cz):
    ux, uy, uz = bx - ax, by - ay, bz - az
    mag = math.sqrt(ux*ux+uy*uy +uz*uz)
    ux, uy, uz = ux / mag, uy / mag, uz / mag
    Cx, Cy, Cz = ax - cx, ay - cy, az - cz
    nx, ny, nz = uy * Cz - uz * Cy, uz * Cx - ux * Cz, ux * Cy - uy * Cx
    mag = math.sqrt(nx*nx+ny*ny+nz*nz)
    nx, ny, nz = nx / mag, ny / mag, nz / mag
    vx, vy, vz = uy * nz - uz * ny, uz * nx - ux * nz, ux * ny - uy * nx
    denom = 1.0 / (ux*ux+uy*uy + uz*uz)
    M = [[0.0]*4 for _ in range(4)]
    M[3][3] = 1.0

    M[0][0] = denom*(ux)
    M[0][1] = denom*(uy)
    M[0][2] = denom*(uz)
    M[0][3] = denom*(-ax*ux-ay*uy+az*uz)

    M[1][0] = denom*(vx)
    M[1][1] = denom*(vy)
    M[1][2] = denom*(vz)
    M[1][3] = -denom*(ax*vx-ay*vy+az*vz)

    M[2][0] = denom*(nx)
    M[2][1] = denom*(ny)
    M[2][2] = denom*(nz)
    M[2][3] = denom*(-ax*nx-ay*ny+az*nz)

    return M

def mult(M, vec):
    res = [0]*4
    for k in range(4):
        for i in range(4):
            res[k] += M[k][i] * vec[i]
    return res

#test corners and middle point
M = calcMatrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
#print(M)
p = [1, 0, 0, 1]
print(mult(M, p))
p = [0, 1, 0, 1]
print(mult(M, p))
p = [0, 0, 1, 1]
print(mult(M, p))
p = [1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1]
print(mult(M, p))
```

test results:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.7071067811865476, 1.2247448713915892, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.7071067811865476, 0.4082482904638631, 1.1102230246251565e-16, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a normal `n` to the polygon, by means of a cross-product between two non-parallel sides. Take the cross-product of `n` with a vertical vector, to get an horizontal vector `u`. Then take the cross product of `n` and `u` to get `v`, and normalize the vectors. `u` and `v` are parallel to the plane of the polygon and orthogonal to each other.

Finally, for every vertex `p` compute the 2D coordinates `(p.u, p.v)` which show you the polygon in its plane.

`numpy` supplies the `cross` and `dot` vector functions. Also `linalg.norm` (or `sqrt(dot(v, v))`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a robust approach using NumPy (`project()`; the rest is test code).

```py
import numpy
import scipy.spatial


def project(x):
    # Center the plane on the origin
    x = x - numpy.mean(x, axis=0)
    # Compute the Singular Value Decomposition
    u, s, v = numpy.linalg.svd(x)
    # Return the top two principal components
    return u[:, :2] @ numpy.diag(s[:2])


def test():
    n = 10
    x = (numpy.random.rand(n, 2) @ numpy.random.rand(2, 3)) + numpy.random.rand(3)
    y = project(x)
    print(x.shape, y.shape)
    print(
        numpy.max(
            numpy.abs(
                scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(x, x)
                - scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(y, y)
            )
        )
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Sample output:

```
(10, 3) (10, 2)
5.551115123125783e-16
```